# Using Webpack and xdan/datetimepicker can't make work that datetimepicker had extended jQuery (to use like this $.fn.datetimepicker)

Tags: jquery, webpack, datetimepicker

I am using ["xdan/datetimepicker" v2.5.4](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker).

In **webpack.config.js** I have:

```
...
module: {
        loaders: [            
            { 
                test: require.resolve('jquery'), //Latest
                loader: 'expose?jQuery!expose?$' 
            }
        ]
},
resolve: {
  alias: {
    "jquery": path.resolve("./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"),
    "jquery.datetimepicker":  path.resolve("./node_modules/jquery-datetimepicker/build/jquery.datetimepicker.full.js")
  }
}
```

In **knockoutBindings.js**:

```
var ko = require('knockout');
require('jquery');

/* Date picker value binder for knockout */
(function (ko) {
    ko.bindingHandlers.datetimepicker = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
            var $element = $(element);
            var value = valueAccessor(), allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
            var valueUnwrapped = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value);
            var options = allBindings.dtPickerOptions || {};

// The error Message: Unable to process binding "datetimepicker: function (){return timeFrom  " Message: $element.datetimepicker is not a function"
            $element.datetimepicker({
                step: 15,
                format: config.timeFormat,
                formatTime: config.timeFormatHours,
                formatDate: config.timeFormatDate,
                onChangeDateTime: function (dp, $input) {
                    var date = moment($input.val(), config.timeFormat);
                    date.set('second', 0);
                    var observable = valueAccessor();
                    observable(date.format(config.timeFormat));
                },
                lang: 'custom',
                i18n : {
                    custom: translationController.datePicker
                }
            });

        },
        update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            var valueUnwrapped = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
            var obs = valueAccessor();
            $(element).val(moment(valueUnwrapped, config.timeFormat).format(config.timeFormat));
        }
    };
})(ko);
```

How to make that "$.fn.datetimepicker" were available in binding?

I tried allot off variants with come to my mind like:

```
//require('jquery.datetimepicker');
//require('imports?this=>window!jquery.datetimepicker');
//require('expose?$.fn.datetimepicker!jquery.datetimepicker');
//$.fn.datetimepicker = require('script!jquery.datetimepicker');
//require('imports?this=>$!jquery.datetimepicker');
//require('expose?$!jquery.datetimepicker');
```

And no one of these were working...

**Note:** Jquery is available and everything is fine with it...

Answer (score 0):

Found sollution.
Simple have to add this peace of code to "**knockoutBindings.js**":

```
require('exports?$!jquery.datetimepicker');
```